# Use Both Standalone Power App and Customized form to update Sharepoint Online List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a Sharepoint Online list. I built both a customized form and a standalone app to update fields in the list in case users wanted to use one or the other. However, is it even possible to have both options function simultaneously on the same list? Or do I have to choose one or the other?

Comment: have you customized your list form using powerapps?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can have multiple apps that all connect to the same list. No issues at all. This is actually a common scenario for things like having one app with typical user features and another app with typical approver features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a customized form attached to a list to add/update items in list and your standalone powerapp which uses connection to the same list will not affect anything.

Even you can create multiple powerapps which uses your list as a data connection in it.

Also, you can change the form settings to choose which form your list should use using below steps:

1. Go to **List Settings**.
2. Go to **Form Settings**.
3. Choose the form you want to set for your list and **Save**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can definitely use both Standalone Power App and Customized form to update SharePoint Online List simultaneously.

You can customized the SharePoint default form to update SharePoint Online List and also at the same time you can create the new PowerApps to update SharePoint Online List which will connect to the Same list.